# Adding Dynamic buttons to display pop-up window to link entries

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor

I am creating a list of entries each with a `Link` button in a `foreach` loop on my Razor Page. The `Link` button is clicked to open a modal with another list of entries and all of these entries have a `checkbox`. This view allows me to `Link` an entry to multiple other entries. Code below for HTML:

```
@foreach (var entry in Model.EntryList.Where(w => w.IsLinked == false))
{
<tr>
  <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">@entry.Description</td>
  <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
      <button id="btnShowModal" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-left col-lg-11 button button4">
        Link
      </button>

      <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="loginModal"
                     data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Link Entries</h4>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                    ×
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@entry.Description" method="post" class="mt-3">
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <table style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th class="text-center">Description</th>
                                                <th class="text-center"></th>                                                    
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>

                                            @foreach (var LinkEntry in Model.EntryList.Where(w => w.IsLinked == true))
                                            {
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">@LinkEntry.Description</td>                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                    <td class="pt-1-half" contenteditable="true">
                                                        <input name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="@LinkEntry.Id" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            }
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary button button4">Link Entries</button>
                                    <button type="button" id="btnHideModal" class="btn btn-primary button button4">
                                        Hide
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  </td>
  </td>
</tr>
}
```

When the `Link` button is clicked the below `jQuery` runs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnShowModal").click(function () {
                $("#loginModal").modal('show');
            });

            $("#btnHideModal").click(function () {
                $("#loginModal").modal('hide');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The current problem I have is that only the first `Link` button shows the `Modal div`. The rest of the `Link` buttons do not do anything when clicked. So I then moved the entire `Modal Div` outside of the `foreach` but does not fix the problem and this then also doesn't allow me to parse the `asp-route-Id` due to now being outside the `foreach`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you are using hard-coded `id`s for your buttons, but they are created in a loop so more than one element with the same `id` is created, which you definitely do not want.

Remove the `id`s and replace them with a unique `class`, like `btn-show-modal`, then change your jquery selector from `$("#btnShowModal")` to `$(".btn-show-modal")`.

Do the same thing with your hide buttons, but use a different unique class name like `btn-hide-modal`. Be sure to do this with all hard-coded `id`s (looks like there is at least one more instance).

One other point I should make is you will need to query the modal relative to the button that is clicked. Inside the click events, you should do `$(this).next().modal('show')` / `$(this).next().modal('hide')` , since as stated, you need to remove the `id="loginModal"` and will need an alternative method to get the correct modal to show.

I believe jquery is smart enough to not search the entire DOM when using the id selector (`#`), so that is why only your first button is firing your click event.

My suggestion to future proof these kinds of errors is to create a `<script>` that will search the DOM for duplicate `id`s and show an `alert()`, or something, to let you know that your DOM is invalid. I'd also make sure that this script is only added when debugging, as with this `<script>` you will catch the errors during development and do not want to the extra overhead in production.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as William says, you have that error because you are using an id and that button is being created so many times as items you have in your collection. And if I was you I'll put the modal outside the first loop because otherwise you can create a lot of modal too. I leave you an example of something that I hope can help you.

This is the model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class SampleViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [MinLength(10)]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        [Display(Name = "Ask Magic 8 Ball any question:")]
        public string Question { get; set; }

        //See here for list of answers
        public string Answer { get; set; }

        public List<Test> EntryList { get; set; }
    }

    public class Test {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsLinked { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Here you are the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var list = new SampleViewModel();
            list.EntryList = new List<Test>();

            var test1 = new Test();
            test1.Id = 1;
            test1.Description = "test1";
            test1.IsLinked = false;
            list.EntryList.Add(test1);

            var test2 = new Test();
            test2.Id = 2;
            test2.Description = "test2";
            test2.IsLinked = false;
            list.EntryList.Add(test2);

            var test3 = new Test();
            test3.Id = 3;
            test3.Description = "test3";
            test3.IsLinked = false;
            list.EntryList.Add(test3);

            var test11 = new Test();
            test11.Id = 11;
            test11.Description = "test11";
            test11.IsLinked = true;
            list.EntryList.Add(test11);

            var test12 = new Test();
            test12.Id = 12;
            test12.Description = "test12";
            test12.IsLinked = true;
            list.EntryList.Add(test12);

            var test21 = new Test();
            test21.Id = 21;
            test21.Description = "test21";
            test21.IsLinked = true;
            list.EntryList.Add(test21);

            var test22 = new Test();
            test22.Id = 22;
            test22.Description = "test22";
            test22.IsLinked = true;
            list.EntryList.Add(test22);

            return View(list);
        }

    }
}
```

And this is the view.

```
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.SampleViewModel
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- template from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started -->

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

  <!-- CSS Includes -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <style type="text/css">
    .field-validation-error {
      color: #ff0000;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          @foreach (var entry in Model.EntryList.Where(w => w.IsLinked == false))
          {
          <tr>
            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">@entry.Description</td>
            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
              <button type="button" onClick="showModal('@entry.Description')" class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-left col-lg-11 button button4">
                Link
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="alert alert-warning fade">
        <img src="http://entechprod.blob.core.windows.net/dotnetfiddle/morpheus.jpg"
          style="max-width:100%;" /><br /><br />
        <strong><span class="alert-content"></span></strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="loginModal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Link Entries</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            ×
          </button>
        </div>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="modalForm" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index"
          asp-route-id="" method="post" class="mt-3">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <table style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="text-center">Description</th>
                  <th class="text-center"></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

                @foreach (var LinkEntry in Model.EntryList.Where(w => w.IsLinked == true))
                {
                <tr>
                  <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">@LinkEntry.Description</td>
                  <td class="pt-1-half" contenteditable="true">
                    <input name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="@LinkEntry.Id" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                }
              </tbody>
            </table>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary button button4">Link Entries</button>
            <button type="button" onClick="hideModal()" class="btn btn-primary button button4">
              Hide
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- JS includes -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        function showModal(desc) {
           $('#modalForm').attr('asp-route-id', desc);
           $("#loginModal").modal('show');
        }

        function hideModal(desc) {
          $("#loginModal").modal('hide');
        }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a modal for each entry in  the loop seems unnecessary to me,
Create a single modal outside your loop and update all its data according with the Link button you clicked

Use data- attributes to pass the info you require to the click event and to build/update your modal, you can JSON your info and use a javascript function to create the table and checkboxes bit

```
@foreach (var entry in Model.EntryList.Where(w => w.IsLinked == false))
{
  <tr>
    <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">@entry.Description</td>
    <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
      <button data-entry-id="@entry.Id" data-entries="<?= htmlentities(json_encode(Model.EntryList.Where(w => w.IsLinked == true)))?>" id="btnShowModal" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-left col-lg-11 button button4 ">
        Link
      </button> ...
```

then you add a listener with JS to all those Link buttons

```
function onClickLinkButtonUpdateModal($e){
  let entries = JSON.parse($e.target.dataset.entries);
  let entry_id = $e.target.dataset.entryId;
  //pass the info you need, you can create the tr elements or the whole tbody with document.create or with template literals
  let tr_entries = generateHTMLEntries(entry_id, entries);
  //assuming you put an id to the table or the table body
  document.querySelector('#modal-table').appendChild(tr_entries);
  //or
  //document.querySelector('#modal-tbody').innerHTML = tr_entries;
}
```